# Quarkus hot replace does not work for code in constructor

Tags: quarkus

I'm following [this rest json tutorial](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-json). After creating the project using maven as described in the tutorial, I start quarkus in dev mode via:

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

The automatically generated project comes with a sample `JacksonResource` type, which has JAX-RS annotations in place. When I visit `http://localhost:8080/resteasy-jackson/quarks` , the REST api works just fine and I see the json payload in the browser.

When I modify the elements of the `Set<Quark>` typed field (by changing code in the constructor) in the resource type and save the file, changes are not reflected in the json payload if I refresh the page.

This is Ubuntu 18.04.
`./mvnw --version` produces:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: /home/<user-name>/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin/1iopthnavndlasol9gbrbg6bf2/apache-maven-3.6.3
Java version: 11.0.10, vendor: GraalVM Community, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/graalvm-ce-java11-21.0.0.2
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.15.0-101-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

What am I missing here?

**Update:**
It looks like the changes to code in the constructor of a type are not reloaded. If I change something in a method, hot reload/replace works as expected. I'm updating the title of the question and content accordingly.

I could not reproduce the works-only-once scenario either. It looks like there are some edge cases.

Comment: what version of Quarkus are you using ? there were some changes/improvements in 1.11 around using instrumentation instead of full restart thus before answering would be good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll assume you use Quarkus 1.11 or higher. In 1.11 instrumentation was added as a way to not do a full restart when only body of methods changed.

Thus I could imagine that what you are seeing is that you are not actually triggering a full restart and thus your new constructor is also not called as it is reusing objects. Could that be the case ?

if yes, and you prefer to have full restart to trigger full reconstruction of your objects then you can set `quarkus.dev.instrumentation=false` and Quarkus will not try and optimize using instrumentation but do a full restart.

If you do believe you are creating full new objects then do please open an issue at https://github.com/quarkus/issues